# Why is Modbus getter not receiving data from Modbus server?

Tags: node-red, modbus

Workflow as follows:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "8433851b34033b3b",
        "type": "modbus-read",
        "z": "1ba6b61acf69773f",
        "name": "test",
        "topic": "test",
        "showStatusActivities": false,
        "logIOActivities": false,
        "showErrors": false,
        "showWarnings": true,
        "unitid": "0",
        "dataType": "Coil",
        "adr": "1",
        "quantity": "1",
        "rate": "1",
        "rateUnit": "m",
        "delayOnStart": false,
        "startDelayTime": "",
        "server": "b242b402bba0f67f",
        "useIOFile": false,
        "ioFile": "",
        "useIOForPayload": false,
        "emptyMsgOnFail": false,
        "x": 370,
        "y": 60,
        "wires": [
            [
                "17c8a4504ad23109"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "17c8a4504ad23109",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "1ba6b61acf69773f",
        "name": "debug 6",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 600,
        "y": 60,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "f1c9a936ac0bce42",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "1ba6b61acf69773f",
        "name": "DO格式",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "true",
        "targetType": "full",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 580,
        "y": 100,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "dc61d5bb20b3e373",
        "type": "modbus-getter",
        "z": "1ba6b61acf69773f",
        "name": "modbus getter",
        "showStatusActivities": true,
        "showErrors": true,
        "showWarnings": true,
        "logIOActivities": false,
        "unitid": "0",
        "dataType": "Coil",
        "adr": "1",
        "quantity": "1",
        "server": "b242b402bba0f67f",
        "useIOFile": false,
        "ioFile": "",
        "useIOForPayload": false,
        "emptyMsgOnFail": false,
        "keepMsgProperties": true,
        "delayOnStart": false,
        "startDelayTime": "",
        "x": 220,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": [
            [
                "f1c9a936ac0bce42",
                "5b83066048133419"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b242b402bba0f67f",
        "type": "modbus-client",
        "name": "Ｍodbus server",
        "clienttype": "tcp",
        "bufferCommands": true,
        "stateLogEnabled": false,
        "queueLogEnabled": false,
        "failureLogEnabled": true,
        "tcpHost": "127.0.0.1",
        "tcpPort": "502",
        "tcpType": "DEFAULT",
        "serialPort": "/dev/ttyUSB",
        "serialType": "RTU-BUFFERD",
        "serialBaudrate": "9600",
        "serialDatabits": "8",
        "serialStopbits": "1",
        "serialParity": "none",
        "serialConnectionDelay": "100",
        "serialAsciiResponseStartDelimiter": "0x3A",
        "unit_id": "0",
        "commandDelay": "1",
        "clientTimeout": "1000",
        "reconnectOnTimeout": false,
        "reconnectTimeout": "2000",
        "parallelUnitIdsAllowed": true,
        "showWarnings": true,
        "showLogs": true
    }
]
```

I am using a Modbus Client Simulator to connect to the Modbus server. Initially, I was using Modbus read to fetch the data, but now I want to replace it with Modbus getter. However, in my tests, only Modbus read is detecting changes from the Modbus server node, while Modbus getter is not. The output is as follows:

```
2023/8/29 9:54:01 node: debug 6
test : msg.payload : array[8]
[true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]

2023/8/29 9:55:01 node: debug 6
test : msg.payload : array[8]
[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

I have already tried comparing the corresponding nodes, and they should be correctly pointing to the Modbus server. The output from the simulator and debug6 is also consistent, so the only remaining issue is why the Modbus getter is not receiving any messages.

What I expect: I would like assistance in getting the Modbus getter to correctly receive information from the Modbus server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported your flow and tried it out with the modbus server of the same package.

The difference between the Getter and Read Nodes is that the Getter reacts on an input message while the Read node can be triggered by the button press or the options in the editor.

Therefore, you just have to add an Inject node in front of the Getter node which injects any kind of message. Now you can either start the Getter with a button press on the Inject node or set an interval there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clearing that up for me! I was actually looking for a way to grab data from the Modbus server node as soon as it comes in from the other side. Looks like the Modbus Getter isn't gonna do the trick. Any other ideas on how I can make this happen?

Comment: @QuantaWu If you mean some kind of event based monitoring for changes, I dont think there is something like this in this modbus package or modbus in general. It is too simple for that. I recommend polling the data you are interested in in an interval as slow as you can allow your application to be. This will make sure network traffic stays as low as can be. Sorry, for not being able to give a proper solution.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Now I have a clear understanding of the correct usage of this node and the limitations of Node-RED. I hope alternative methods can be developed in the future.